# Atribuição de operação em C

Tags: c, tipagem

Não entendo por que ao fazer esta operação, mesmo já tendo declarado o `r` como `float`, se não colocar o operador de *cast* se atribui um `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    float r;
    r = (float) 8 * 2 / 3;
    printf("O resultado eh: %.2f", r); // Sem o cast r= 5.00 que é errado.
}
```

Comment: Porque você está dividindo por `3` e não por `3.0`... Faça `r = 8*2/3.0;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa do *cast*, mas precisa usar um número que indique que é um `float` de alguma forma. Tanto o `8`, quanto o `2` quanto o `3` são números inteiros, então quando ele fizer os cálculos eles gerarão números inteiros, não há um *cast* implícito só porque teve uma divisão que potencialmente poderia dar uma parte decimal. Se quer a parte decimal então diga isto.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    printf("O resultado eh: %.2f", 8.0 * 2.0 / 3.0);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nVjxwv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qxpjkrbk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/FloatDivision2.c).

Precisa colocar a parte decimal em todos? Neste caso não precisa, mas tem caso que pode precisar por causa da precedência e associatividade. Se está trabalhando com `float` use literais que já sejam `float`.

Comment: Entendi, devo deixar explicito no calculo em ao menos um número. Obrigado!

Comment: No número mais importante, não é que basta em um, pode ser em um, depende do local. Em vez do literal poderia usar o *cast*, mas é feio.